# Create a new folder warning that that folder exists?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, directory, move, scanning

This is my code for creating new folder on disk D:\Scan folder and save *.pdf files in folder that I creating with this script. All is working fine, but now my question is can I get some warning when I created folder earlier (for example I created folder Z-1990-21 yesterday and today I created same folder Z-1990-21) so if I want to create (replace) that same folder when I press enter on keyboard it will be created (replaced) on or when I press esc (escape) the folder will not be created?

thx..

```
: start
cd /D D:\Scan\Scan2021
set /p x= Example (1990):
md Z-%x%-21
move D:\"Scan"\*.PDF* D:\"Scan\Scan2021\Z-%x%-21
cls && goto start
```

Comment: `IF EXIST "Z-%x%-21\" echo the folder exists.`

Comment: If you replace the directory, what's supposed to happen to any files already inside it? What is `Example (1990)` supposed to mean? If I get a prompt to enter something, I expect the prompt to tell me what it would like me to do, not just show me a statement that asks me nothing? Is the end user supposed to guess what that means? What exactly are they supposed to enter? a four digit string? a string of any number of digits? a valid year in `YYYY` format between two particular years? any string of any number of characters? only alphanumeric characters? And why return to start with no PDF's left?

Comment: If you don't need to know if the directory already exists for other purposes, but wish to avoid the default "already exist" STDERR from `md`: `md Z-%x%-21 2> nul`

Comment: Otherwise, use conditional operation: `md Z-%x%-21 || Goto :start`

Answer (score 0):

The files in that folder should remain inside that folder if you want to replace the existing folder (by pressing enter).
This is just an example of 1990 (the name of the folder I create twice, for example)